# How to select a record with upcoming date and time?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I have this table called `events`. This table contains `event_date` and `event_time` in separate columns. I'm currently working on a page where it will show all the upcoming events. How do I query records from the `events` table where the date and time are still upcoming? I mean, how do I calculate or write the query, specifically the `where` clause, using MySQL? I'm using PHP and CodeIgniter.

Thanks to everyone who will answer.

EDIT: I used Gordon Linoff's suggestion:

```
where event_date >= now() or
      (event_date = date(now()) and event_time > time(now()))
```

But I modified it to

```
where event_date>date(now()) or
      (event_date=date(now()) and event_time>time(now()))
```

Because Gordon's didn't quite return the result I was expecting (Events which are dated on the current day but the time has not yet come were not appearing as upcoming events). Anyway, thanks Gordon and to other people who answered. I am not yet an expert in MySQL date queries, so you guys did me a huge favor.

Comment: do you want the `WHERE` clause or `ORDER BY` functionality?

Comment: Upcoming event means it's date is in future, compared to today. Therefore it would be something like `WHERE date_column > NOW()`

Comment: What datatypes do you use for storing the date and time portions?

Comment: or you might need all events from now-on and not events that have past?

Comment: What if it is on the same day but the time has not yet come @N.B.?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I'm using date for date and time for time.

Comment: @N.B. Of course, that would fail for an event at 17:00 on the current day (assuming it's prior to 17:00) as the date and time are stored in separate columns

Comment: @RowlandShaw I love how you guys immediately started tearing me a new one, without realizing that I posted the **comment** in order to turn someone's attention to where to look for the answer. I don't like spoonfeeding people, especially with trivial matter such as date/time manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use:

```
where event_date >= now() or
      (event_date = date(now()) and event_time > time(now()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM events where event_date > DATE(NOW()) AND event_time > TIME(NOW());
```

Comment: This would fail for stuff at 8:00 the following morning (assuming you were querying after 8:00), and also fail for stuff on the current day at 17:00 (if querying before 17:00)